# Gloxinia has twisted leaves

Tags: houseplants

I have more gloxies, which i care for the same, and that all are in the same place, but i do not know why some of them turn their leaves. Can you help me? Thanks a lot![image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The leaves are not so much twisted as flopping and rolling  downwards, an indication that the plant is suffering a bit of drought. There are what might be roots in the water container  at the bottom of the plant, which suggests the soil in the pot is dry, and the only access to water the plant has is via extended roots sitting in water at the bottom there.

This problem would be resolved by standing the pot in a tray or saucer, watering the soil, then allowing excess water to drain away freely at the bottom, with the tray being emptied out after 30 minutes so the plant is not left sitting in water. Whilst Gloxinia grows from a tuber which is prone to rot in wet conditions, they do not like to be sitting in dry soil whilst they are in full growth with blooms in place, and need to be kept damp; water should be applied  direct  to the soil in the pot, preferably without getting any on the leaves and crown of the plant, rather like African violets.

You now have a problem though, if those are roots in the bottom container... it is not a good idea to repot these unless they are dormant, and yours aren't, obviously, but they do need repotting so that roots are not extruding from the bottom. More info here https://www.thespruce.com/grow-senningia-hybrids-indoors-1902487

Comment: I wet the flowers with the wick-watering metod. Do you think this method is not good for gloxi?

Comment: Well its not one I'd choose - the method you have chosen means the soil can get very dry, which is what is causing  the drooping/rolling leaves  on some of them

Comment: I agree with the other poster. Usually dropping its the first sign of lack of water. The method of watering you have its not effective all the time. Water them and see how fast they go back to normal.